# Replace text of a specific line number using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a html file `users.html` that i want to replace the first line. The first line looks like this

```
<template name="AccountSettings">
```

I want the first line to read

```
<template name="Users">
```

Comment: It is prudent to use an XML parser to parse XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commands in `sed` accept an *address range*. In this case, to limit the replacement to just the first line, the range should be the single address `1` i.e.

```
sed '1 s/AccountSettings/Users/' users.html
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Perl

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/AccountSettings/Users/ if $. == 1' input.txt
```

- `-pi` allows to make changes for input file in-place, i.e. alter the actual file. If you want to see result before overwriting the file, use `-p` instead
- `s/AccountSettings/Users/` perform first substitution for pattern.
- `$.` is processed line count

#### AWK

```
$ awk 'NR==1{sub("AccountSettings","Users")};1' input.txt                
<template name="Users">
AccountSettings
```

- `NR==1{sub("AccountSettings","Users")}` is `Pattern or Condition {actions}` structure typical of awk. Action is performed when condition is true.
- `NR==1{}` is number of processed lines, specifically we're looking if number of lines is equal to 1.
- `sub("AccountSettings","Users")` performs replacement for the first match of the pattern.
- `1` is pattern with omitted action. Default action for pattern that is true is to print, and making pattern to be `1` ensures we print resulting lines.

#### Python

One liner with reading `stdin`:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print("\n".join([ l.strip().replace("AccountSettings","Users") if i==0 else l.strip()  for i,l in enumerate(sys.stdin)]))' < input.txt
```

Script version:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv;
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    for index,line in enumerate(f):
        text = line.strip().replace("AccountSettings","User") if index == 0 else line.strip()
        print(text)
```

- core idea is to either redirect `stdin` stream and read lines from there or provide file as `argv[1]` - first command-line argument to script
- We use `variable = value_1 if condition else value_2` structure to build up a list of lines with appropriate values in one-liner, while in script version assignment to `text` variable and immediate printing of that variable is performed. The condition for the replacement is of course line number

#### Ruby

```
$ ruby -pe '$_=$_.sub(/AccountSettings/,"Users") if $. == 1' input.txt                                                                             
<template name="Users">
AccountSettings
```

- Similar idea to Perl, `-p`  switch  allows us to print `$_` (current line) variable each time.
- `$_=$_.sub(/AccountSettings/,"Users") if $. == 1`  is `action if condition` structure,where we use `.sub()` function to perform pattern 
  replacement and assign it back to `$_` buffer if line number is 1

Comment: Nice answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Use following command:

```
sed   's/name="AccountSettings"/name="Users"/g' users.html
```